# custom alertDialog in android

Tags: android

I'm working with custom alertDialog in android and found a problem. My code is simple:

```
LayoutInflater inflatre = getLayoutInflater();
View v = inflatre.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditPageActivity.this);
dialog.setView(v);
dialog.show();
```

And the layout xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="center" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gallery_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gallery" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/photo_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gallery_b"
    android:text="Take Photo" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gallery_b"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Choose Image"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/splash_font"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

But the output is like this:

[image]

Feeling helpless after searching google :(...can anyone describe me anything

Comment: set `android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to your main layout and try

Comment: remove the padding or either use dialog back ground image bigger in height or just manually set the height of the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout for `Dialog`, It should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Choose Image"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textColor="@color/splash_font"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gallery_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Gallery" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallery_b"
        android:text="Take Photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: well... thanks bro, your layout worked for me.... can you please describe the facts why my layout didn't work like yours.... my layout is almost similar to yours though...

Comment: @MostafaImran note these alignment parameter.
`<TextView`
 `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

`/>`
`<Button`
 `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"`
`/>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); // your layout id
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);  // button in your layout
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

//Try this one:

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature((int) Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_here);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        dialog.show();
```